# Typescript function returning value without null or undefined

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function which returns a value or if the value is null or undefined it should return a default value.

```js
function test<A, B>(input: A, fallbackValue: B): NonNullable<A> | B {
 if (input == null || input == undefined) {
   return fallbackValue;
 } else {
   return input;
 }
}
```

I get the error

```
Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B | NonNullable<A>'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<A>'.
```

NonNullable should be A without null or undefined and that's what I checked in the if?

[Here is the code in ts playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgIIBpEBCAfABQxgAOIUAXInosAIYA2LARkxANYBqrIFHQIBKOgDkE4kGybsWKHEUQAfQogDeAWABQifYhjBEZStUQBeC4jAyWqteSpRL18ABMUwcincjNugZBiABOKFAgIUjMbJw8-CyCANyBBgC+iCgsaCgBesH6YRFRhmZQKfn6abppQA)

Comment: Aren't your if and else branches swapped?

Comment: Woops, yes. Fixed it in the example, but the error is the same :)

Comment: You're declaring `input: A` but returning a `NonNullable<A>`. It appears you'll either need to declare `input: NonNullable<A>` or return `A | B`. You could cast your return type to `NonNullable<A>` but that may be a logic error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional type (of which `NonNullable` is) usually don't provide a good implementation in generic functions. You could use a type assertion to get it to work (`return input as any`);

A safer approach might be to switch up the types a bit:

```
function test<A, B>(input: A | undefined | null, fallbackValue: B): A | B {
    if (input == null || input == undefined) {
        return fallbackValue;
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}

declare var s: string | null;
let a = test(s, "") // string
```

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Your solution works for me. But was my usage of NonNullable wrong or is this a bug/missing feature in typescript or is it working as intended?

Comment: @Dirk it's a limitation (not sure if it is addressable in the future)